# How do I concatenate a string stored in variable and a number in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, concatenation

I am trying to read a tag from XML and then want to concatenate a number to it.
Firstly, I am saving the value of the string to a variable and trying to concatenate it 
with the variable in the for loop. But it throws an error.

```
for i = 0:tag.getLength-1
                node = tag.item(i);
                disp([node.getTextContent]);

                str=node.getTextContent;

                str= strcat(str, num2str(i))
                new_loads = cat(2,loads,[node.getTextContent]);                
            end
```

Error thrown is

```
Operands to the || and && operators must be
convertible to logical scalar values.

Error in strcat (line 83)
if ~isempty(str) && (str(end) == 0 ||
isspace(str(end)))

Error in SMERCGUI>pushbutton1_Callback (line 182)
                str= strcat(str,' morning')

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 96)
    feval(varargin{:});

Error in SMERCGUI (line 44)
gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in
@(hObject,eventdata)SMERCGUI('pushbutton1_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

Comment: so the error is in the line `str= strcat(str, num2str(i))`, correct? You can also try, `str=[str num2str(i)]`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error suggests that your string is not a string. It's not clear to me whether it's throwing an error at the `strcat` line, or at the later `cat` line.

At any rate, it should be clear that you cannot concatenate elements of different types into an array - cell array yes, regular array no. So the line

```
new_loads = cat(2,loads,[node.getTextContent]);
```

is bound to give a problem. `2` is numerical, and `node.getTextContent` is a string - or maybe a cell array or something else. I can't see what `loads` is, so I can't tell if that is involved in the problem.

Usually a good way to combine numbers and strings into a single string is

```
newString = sprintf('%s %d', oldString, number);
```

You can then use all the formatting tricks of `printf` to produce output exactly as you want. But before you do anything, make sure you understand the type of all the elements you are trying to string together. The easiest way to do this for all the elements in memory is

```
whos
```

Or if you just want it for one variable,

```
whos str
```

Or all variables starting with s:

```
whos s*
```

The output is self-explanatory. If you still can't figure it out after this, leave a comment and I'll try to help you out.

**EDIT** based on what I read at http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2010/11/01/xml-and-matlab-navigating-a-tree/ , it is possible that you just need to cast your `str` variable to a Matlab string (apparently it's a java.lang.string). So try to add

```
str = char(str);
```

before using `str`. It may be what you need.