# Octave: How can I create a string made from 2 strings and a variable?

Tags: string, save, concatenation, octave, filenames

I want to for-loop through some values and for each value of the index I want to save an image to the disk. Is there a way to achieve the following:

```
N = 16;
name_RGB = ["RGBN" N ".jpeg"];

imwrite(image1, name_RGB, "jpeg");
```

??

So to explain, the loop is currently on index 16. I want to save an image with the name "RGBN16.jpeg". Anyone know if it is possible to join strings and variables together in Octave?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I concatenate a string stored in variable and a number in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20694149/how-do-i-concatenate-a-string-stored-in-variable-and-a-number-in-matlab)

Comment: Look at `newString = sprintf('%s %d', oldString, number)` in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20696062/3565696)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to convert the numeric value to a string, then you can concatenate, like this:

```
N = 16;
name_RGB = ["RGBN" num2str(N) ".jpeg"];

imwrite(image1, name_RGB, "jpeg");
```

For more options, see the documentation here:

https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Converting-Numerical-Data-to-Strings.html

Comment: Literally just got it as you submitted the answer!!! Thanks for your troubles all the same :)

Comment: I would use something like `fn=sprintf ("RGBN%i.jpeg", N);`

Comment: @whatwhatwhat: Please consider accepting this as answer if it answers your question even if you found the answer yourself just before you read gariepys answer.